# Android: How to populate a spinner from saved openFileOutput Mode_PRIVATE?

Tags: android, spinner, populate, fileoutputstream

What i want to achieve is populating a spinner with previously created openFileOutput files.

This is the code for creating the files:

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FILENAME = filename.getText().toString();
                COMMENTS = comments.getText().toString();
                try {
                    FileOutputStream f = openFileOutput(FILENAME,
                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    f.write(COMMENTS.getBytes());
                    f.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Saved",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });
```

So for example: I create these 3 files with the code above:
File1
File2
File3

I want my spinner to look like this:

File1

File2

File3

The problem i'm having is that i have no clue to how this is done.

I google searched it, but unfortunately no results.

Can someone explain to me how to achieve this, preferably with sample code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

It's really simple just use fileList ().

Populate an array with fileList (). And use that array as third argument of the arrayadapter.